# Two declarations cause a collision in ObjectFactory class

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, netbeans-8, wsimport

I am trying to create web service clients for the following wsdl.

https://sgtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/BookingManager.svc?wsdl

But it keeps throwing the above mentioned error. Tried creating bindings.xml file with separate package for each xsd mentioned in the import section of the wsdl. But that didnt help. Is there any other way to solve this problem. I am using netbeans 8.0.2.

A look at the xsd I found this.

```
 <xs:complexType name="TicketRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SegmentTicketRequests" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSegmentTicketRequest"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="TicketRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:TicketRequest"/>
```

2 variables with same name. There many such variable pairs. How do I handle this?

Comment: observed that xsds are imported multiple tims..any workaround for this?